# How to refresh only a specific function in php?

Tags: php, html, refresh

I have a function to show current date and time using date() function in php. 
I used

```
     meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30" to refresh the whole page.
```

But i want to refresh only that specific function part as i want to change the time every minute. Is it possible?

Comment: You do not want to use PHP for this, it will kill your server. Use something client side...jquery, ajax, javascript...

Comment: i know there are other ways .But i am new to php and not quite familiar with ajax or jquery .is it only possible using ajax or jquery?

Comment: Javascript is incredibly similar to php. Almost a sister language. It is not hard to learn, and yes it is only recommended with client side scripting. Echo the current date and time in a div, and then run the script from @AliGajani below, to update that div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, no it is not possible with just PHP and HTML.

Once your page has been generated by your PHP script, it is sent to the client and cannot be modified anymore. HTML is made to build "static" web pages, that mean they won't produce fancy moving things and therefore they won't update content once the page is loaded.

But even if you cannot send the page a second time once it has been generated by PHP, you're not bound to HTML in the page. You can set up script in the page that will for example make the client browser perform a request to your server to update part of the page. That's called [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AJAX), and to do it you have to learn [Javascript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Javascript).

Answer (score 2):

You should use client-side magic for this, so I'd use AJAX techniques.

```
setInterval(function(){
    $("#time").load("page.php #time");
}, 30000);
```

Justin E asks, you can actually load a specific element from a page. Yes you [can](http://api.jquery.com/load/#urldatacallback).

Comment: You can actually load just a specific element from a page? I never knew that...

Comment: You can: http://api.jquery.com/load/#urldatacallback

Comment: I just created an API and performed ajax requests to the API to get a response, but the ability to reload just that one element means I can simply reload the page and update the contents using the same id there. Thank you so much for that tidbit of helpful knowledge, and the link.

Comment: Anytime Justin, glad you asked. Glad I helped